# Add comment triggers fail in first post review audit?

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3018428

I was going to add a comment for the guy to post his solution as an answer!

Come on! :-)

Now, seriously, why do you assume adding a comment is a bad review in this cases?

Post link: [Achieving bright, vivid colors for an iOS 7 translucent UINavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897485/achieving-bright-vivid-colors-for-an-ios-7-translucent-uinavigationbar)

Comment: For whom? I don't see any comment worth promoting to an answer. Anyways, it's a known issue that commenting on a known-good audit counts as failure.

Comment: @JanDvorak note that the OP has an edit "Updated with solution", whose contents are better suited as an answer. Also remember that other answers and comments are hidden in the review page. If this is a known issue, please flag as duplicate.

Comment: ah, true. Did you check the question if the poster had already posted his solution as an answer? If that was the case, just rollback. At this point, you should notice a disrepancy and work with the review as a known good-audit